# CssSelector and LinkText

Tags: c#, selenium

HTML

```
    <small style="white-space: nowrap;">
    "("
    <a href="../src/left_main.php" target="left">Sprawdź pocztę</a>
    ")"
    </small>
```

I cant find it by:

```
driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("a[href*='/src/left_main.php']")).Click();
```

And the second thing is:

HTML

```
<a href="/sq/src/signout.php" target="_top">
Kliknij tutaj, aby się wylogować
</a>
```

Cant find with that:

```
driver.FindElement(By.LinkText("Kliknij tutaj, aby się wylogować")).Click();
```

Comment: First is correct and is working dues to some other reasons. Second one is probably wrong due to utf-8 encoding. Try to search via link by itself.

Comment: what exception is it throwing?

Answer (score 0):

try this(didnt try, but must work):

```
driver.FindElement(By.Xpath(".//a[@href='../src/left_main.php']")).Click();
```

In second example also better to use the same -- xpath.